# get element from map column via key in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

i want to create a new column from a map column on a data frame ,
i found nothing about access value  by key in spark

so i write my own udf for doing this

```
def getMap(m:Map[Int,Int],key:Int):Option[Int]={
m.get(key)
}
val getMapUdf= udf(getMap _)
```

this solution is simple but not widely use
i expected a func can get generics type getMap function
like this(failed)

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
def getMapG[K:TypeTag,V:TypeTag](m:Map[K,V],key:K]:Option[K]
val getMapGUdf= udf(getMapG _)
```

---

my envirment

spark-v `2.4.5` 
scala-v `2.11.12`

my expected is like this

```
df.withColumn("value_of_key1",getMapG(col("map_col"),col("key1")))
```

thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a builtin function, [`element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#element_at)